# How to check a file is video type or not in php?

Tags: php, file, video, mime-types

I have following script:

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li>'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}
listFolderFiles('upload');
```

My question is I want to detect a file is video(mp4 or mov)type, How i can detect $ff is a video type or not?

Comment: You could use the `file` command, if you are on *nix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if(end(explode(".",$ff)) =="mp4")
{
echo "its an mp4 movie";
}
```

There you go, for case insensitive version of the extension

```
<?php
$ff="abc.MP4";
if(strtolower(end(explode(".",$ff))) =="mp4")
{
echo "its an mp4 movie";
}
?>
```

Comment: And what if I uploaded `mymovie.MP4` ?

Comment: you could simply add an strtolower check

Comment: And what if I uploaded `mymovie.mpeg4` ?

Comment: I hope you get my point. Checking the extension is not a fool proof way to detecting file formats. I could still upload a text file as `movie.mp4`. Use a tool like `file` instead.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I agree

Answer (score 10):

```
    // Type contains video/mp4,video/avi,video/mpeg,video/mpg etc
    if(preg_match('/video\/*/',$_FILES['add_image_image']['type'])): 
        echo "THIS IS A VIDEO FILE";
    else:
          echo "NOT A VIDEO FILE";           
    endif;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `mime_content_type`[mime_content_type php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)

```
if (mime_content_type($dir.'/'.$ff)=='video/mp4')
    echo "its mp4";
```

Answer (score 5):

I use this code:

```php
$mimeType = mime_content_type(public_path('uploads/' . $file));
$fileType = explode('/', $mimeType)[0]; // video|image

if ($fileType === 'video') {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use a tool like [`file`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file).  This answer is security aware, and a general response to uploaded file types.   The second advantage to using `file` is it will tell you more detail about the format used.  There are alot of combinations of formats that may be legitimately stored inside a '*.mpg' file.  You may not be able to deal with all of them.

I did a more detailed websearch, there is a list of duplicate text articles, but no reliable solutions posted.   There is a "magic bytes" detector in the form of [fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php).  This is compiled into most recent versions of PHP (its a standard extension).

NB: mime_content_type() is deprecated.  Again, if you need to, try [fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php)

Comment: The link to file is dead

Comment: [mime_content_type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) doesn't seem to have a deprecated notice, and does seem to be listed as part of [the collection of fileinfo functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You can achive with `preg_match`

```
if(preg_match('/^.*\.(mp4|mov)$/i', $filename)) {
    echo $filename;
}
```

You can append another video ext like: `(mp4|mov|mpg|mpeg|wmv|mkv)`

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this. Should be fairly accurate and performant

```
<?php 
 function isVideo($file) {
   return is_file($file) && (0 === strpos(mime_content_type($file), 'video/'));
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently use this to get the file type i.e. image or video:

```
explode('/', $request->article_thumbnail->getMimeType())[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the mime type of the uploading file and check the type like below,

```
$mime = $file->getMimeType;
$videoJS = array('video/mp4','video/ogg','video/webm');

if(array_search($mime, $videoJS) !== false) {
    //do upload
}
```

Comment: If you want any type of code quality, please do not rely on MIME type submitted by the client.  Use `file` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileType = exec( 'file --mime-type '.escapeshellarg($filePath)); //e.g. output -> /tmp/somefile.mov: video/quicktime
$fileType = substr($fileType, strpos($fileType, ": ") + 2); //strip away file path -> video/quicktime
$fileType = substr($fileType, 0,strpos($fileType, "/")); //strip away whatever video type -> video
if ($fileType == 'video') $fileType = 'im a video!';
```

This code uses unix 'file' command with the option --mime-type to minimize the output for easier parsing. Not sure if there is a better way of parsing the output.

Also make sure you have read permission of the file you are checking.